# How to calculate angle between camera and object

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I´m doing an application to detect, decode, measure distance and angle of a QR Code posted on a wall at certain height.

For that i'm using the raspberry camera module attach to a Raspberry Pi B+, UV4L framework, Python 2.7, OpenCV 2.3 and Zbar. Using Zbar and OpenCV i succesfully detect, decode and measure the distance from the camera to the detected QR Code.

Also, UV4L is used for compatibility between Opencv and Raspicam. I use the HTTP Streaming server that UV4L framework contain. Using cv2.VideoCapture(), i open the stream and then process the frames looking for the QR Code

After i successfully detect the QR Code using Zbar, i extract the four corners of the QRCode and using simple Math i calculate the distance from camera to QR Code

The Raspicam is already calibrated and i got the instrinsic and distortion matrix.
Here is the data i have:

1. Instrinsic and distortion parameters
2. 4 X,Y pixel points regarding the 4 corners of the QR Code
3. Distance in meters from camera to QR Code
4. Field of View of the Raspicam : 54x41 degrees
5. Camera Resolution: 640 x480

The problem is that i haven't being able to find a proper way to calculate the angle between the camera and the QR Code.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Here is the python code i´ve been using.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import zbar
import math
import time


#width of the object
qrwcoord = 0
qrPL = 0
qrNorm = 0
box = 0
focalLenght = 608 #Calibration data
intrinsic = np.array([[608.14578, 0, 292.31368], [0, 608.82584, 261.47420], [0, 0, 1]])  #3x3 Calibration intrinsic matrix
distortion = np.array([ [0.02232355, -0.11265588, 0.00247792, -0.00201052, 0.22786218]]) #1x5 Distortion vector

def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth

def decode_QR(image):
    global box

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    (height, width)=gray.shape
    raw = str(gray.data)
    scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
    scanner.parse_config('enable')
    image1 = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)
    scanner.scan(image1)
    for symbol in image1:
        TLC, BLC, BRC, TRC = [item for item in symbol.location]
        box = np.array([[TLC],[TRC],[BRC],[BLC]])
        qrData=symbol.data
        qrStrip = []
        qrStrip = qrData.split(';')
        qrNorm = qrStrip[0] #Qr Code norm vector
        qrPL = qrStrip[1]
        qrwcoord = qrStrip[2] #QR Code World Coordinates
        qrPL=float(qrPL) #Qr Code size in meters

        print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data
        qrpixelwidth = math.sqrt((TLC[0]-TRC[0])**2+(TLC[1]-TRC[1])**2)
        qrpixelheight = math.sqrt((BLC[0]-BRC[0])**2+(BLC[1]-BRC[1])**2)

        pixel_size = float(qrPL/qrpixelwidth) #Pixel Size in meter
        plane_x_size = float(pixel_size*640)
        plane_y_size = float(pixel_size*480)

        dist = distance_to_camera(qrPL, focalLenght, qrpixelwidth)
        print qrNorm
        print qrPL
        print qrwcoord
        print box
        print qrpixelwidth
        print qrpixelheight
        print "Distance from QR to Camera is:", dist
        print qrStrip
        return box

cv2.namedWindow("Streaming...")
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.open('http://192.168.5.2:8080/stream/video.mjpeg')
while True:
    (grabbed, img) = capture.read()
    if not grabbed:
        break
    box = decode_QR(img)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Streaming...", img)
    #time.sleep(0.05)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyWindow("Streaming...")
```